# Ler Duas Notas e Fazer Media Caso Sejam Notas Válidas

Tags: java, eclipse, lógica

Estou com dificuldades de resolver o exercício abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Devo usar `Desvio Condicional`

E pelos meus "pensamentos" acredito que devo usar o `Desvio Encadeado`

Sei que ambas as notas devem atender o critério de terem valores entre 0 e 10, e só assim poderei fazer a média!
Pensei em usar apenas o 'IF' (que sera para caso atenda os "requisitos" e o 'ELSE' para exibir a mensagem caso uma das notas não for válida!

Estou pensando corretamente? E se sim,que não consegui "indentificar" quais serão as condiçoes que devo colocar no IF em relação as notas!

Comment: Carol apenas uma observação em relação às suas perguntas. Se pensou numa forma de resolver e ainda que instruções utilizar, porque não coloca as suas tentativas de resolução ? Isso ajuda a qualquer pessoa que queira responder pois percebe qual a sua real dificuldade.

Comment: Eh que geralmente quando venho perguntar não tenho resolução feita!
Ai não consigo e acabo perguntando!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há mistério! Um [desvio composto](https://infoanalucia.wordpress.com/sobre/tomada-decisao/desvio-condicional-composto/) pode ser suficiente, a não ser que você tenha em mente algo mais sofisticado.

```
public class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double nota1 = 0, nota2 = 10, media;
        // Verifique se as duas notas obedecem o critério...
        if((nota1 >= 0 && nota1 <= 10) && (nota2 >= 0 && nota2 <= 10)) {
            // ... Se sim, calcule a média
            media = (nota1 + nota2)/2;
            System.out.printf("%.2f", media); // Perceba o uso de printf para dar precisão ao valor de output
        } else {
            System.out.println("Uma das notas é negativa ou maior que 10.");
        }
    }
}
```

Se você alterar os valores iniciais das variáveis, verá que o código acima, simples, atende os requisitos do desafio.

Comment: Era extamente isso que estava pensando,so não sabia se usava apenas If ou usava tambem Else If!